# Custom curl CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER with result [Authentication-API-Key] => 123456

Tags: php, curl

A http connection requires a HTTP POST request with a custom header object Authentication-API-Key

With CURL it's automatically converted to  [HTTP_AUTHENTICATION_API_KEY] => 12345
Cannot figure out why

A simplle extract from a php class for testing is

Please help me out, how to get a $_SERVER result with [Authentication-API-Key] => 123456

```
<?php
    $contentType = 'text/xml';
    $method = 'POST';
    $auth = '';
    $header1 = 'Authentication-API-Key: 12345';
    $charset= 'ISO-8859-1';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost/test/returnurl.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, Array('Content-type: ' . 
                $contentType . '; charset=' . $charset,
                $header1));
curl_exec($ch);

?>

<?php
//http://localhost/test/returnurl.php
Print_r($_SERVER,true)
?>
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [HTTP_HOST] => localhost
    [HTTP_ACCEPT] => */*
    [CONTENT_TYPE] => text/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1
    [HTTP_AUTHENTICATION_API_KEY] => 12345
    ...
)
```

Comment: `header2` seems undefined, could it be the problem?

Comment: Have you tried reading the headers using `get_headers` rather than `$_SERVER`?

Answer (score 1):

If I run your code, I get the message that `$header2` is undefined, so I think you need to fix that. 
If I remove `$header2`, this is the output:

```
GET /test/returnurl.php HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Accept: */*
Content-type: text/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1
Authentication-API-Key: 12345
```

So that seems to be okay. What is your output? Note that currently the request is send using GET, not POST.

EDIT: I created the script `/test/returnurl.php` that simply dumps the `$_SERVER` array, now I see what you mean. The fact that it ends up like that on the receiving end does not mean that you haven't set the header correctly, so the service that you're using should be receiving it as intended.

Comment: the problem is not the var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT)); but the var_dump($_SERVER) in the target url Array
(
    [HTTP_HOST] => localhost
    [HTTP_ACCEPT] => */*
    [CONTENT_TYPE] => text/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1
    [HTTP_AUTHENTICATION_API_KEY] => 12345

Comment: I updated my answer as well; but I don't think that the fact that it ends up in the $_SERVER array like that means you haven't set the header correctly.

Comment: they receive it also as HTTP_AUTHENTICATION_API_KEY

Comment: Does it work for other users who use their API? Do they use PHP's curl?

Comment: They don't use PHP as platform, I'm the only one. The customer explained me that hey never got this question before and that all clients are sending it correctly as [Authentication-API-Key] => 12345

Comment: The strange thing about this is that PHP prepends the header values with "HTTP_" on the requests it _receives_, so it should send the headers like you intend...

Answer (score 0):

That's how `_SERVER` works; it does not give you the HTTP header keys verbatim.

It is not CURL doing this. Examine the *actual* HTTP request and you'll see that your header is fine.

Another example is `$_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE']`, which gives you the value of the `Content-Type` HTTP header.

There is no problem here.

Answer (score -5):

A script I am using passes an array like array("Content-type: image/png").

Perhaps by putting it in an array you prevent it from breaking into an array at the :

I am new to cURL so I haven't even been able to test this theory yet..